# How to make related functions and procedures into one unit in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to make related procedures and functions into single unit like packages in sql and access from that like

PackageName. Function() in mysql

Is it possible in MySQL if so explain with simple example.

Comment: What do you mean using the term "related"? *Is it possible in MySQL* No problems to create your own service database and create all functions/procedures in it. Then you can use them in your code specifying function/procedure name with database name part. Like `SELECT libs.myfunction(fieldname), ...` where `libs` is the name of service database, and `myfunction` is the name of the function defined in that database.

Comment: Can you please explain with example little more please. I want to group functions and procedures and call required one

Comment: Point to unclear moment, I'll explain more wide.

Comment: Consider the following example in sql.   I want to do in MySQL.                                                      
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY guru99_get_set
IS 
PROCEDURE set_record(p_emp_rec IN emp%ROWTYPE)
IS                                                                            statements that I want to write. 
END set_record;
FUNCTION get_record(p_emp_no IN NUMBER)
RETURN number 
END guru99_get_set:
/                           
I want to call like this in MySQL.  guru99_get_set.set_record(1_emp_rec);

Comment: Use `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS` instead of creating package. Create functions/procedures in that database by common way (replacing old versions if needed). Then you can use them.

Comment: You may additionally create a textual help for this database and its content, and insert it into `mysql.help_*` tables for to use it in CLI (mysql Server-Side Help).